# Rotate rectangle image inside frame in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to rotate an rectangle image inside a frame with the same size like this:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;width:208px;height:250px">
 <img style="width:208px;height:250px" src="https://www.webslake.com/w_img/t_i/lpw.png" [style.transform]="styles"> </div>

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-undo btn-lg" (click)="rotateImage('left')">
```

and the button that rotate the image:

```
rotateImage(direction) {    
    if (direction === 'left') {
      this.rotationAmount = this.rotationAmount + -90;
    } else if(direction === 'right') {
      this.rotationAmount = this.rotationAmount + 90;
    }
    this.styles =  'rotate(' + this.rotationAmount + 'deg)';

  }
```

How can I do the rotation inside the div frame without changing the width and the height, because if I rotate the (new)width = old(height) and vice versa I want to have the same width and height during the rotation.

Comment: use `[style.width/height]` as you set the `transform`

Comment: is not working, and I need to scale the image when I do the rotate. to fit inside the frame

Answer (score 0):

I added logic to calculate top and left to style:

```
rotateImage(direction: string) {

 if (direction === 'left') {
   let flag = this.width;
   this.width = this.height;
   this.height = flag;
   this.rotationAmount = this.rotationAmount + -90;
   if (this.rotationAmount == -360) {
    this.rotationAmount = 0;
   }
  console.log(this.rotationAmount);
   if (this.rotationAmount === -180 || this.rotationAmount === 0) {
     this.top = 0;
     this.left = 0;
   } else {
     this.top = (this.width-this.height)/2 * (-1); 
     this.left = (this.width-this.height)/2;
     console.log(this.top, this.left)
   }
} 

 else if(direction === 'right') {
   this.rotationAmount = this.rotationAmount + 90;
 }
 this.styles =  'rotate(' + this.rotationAmount + 'deg)';
}
```

It's a link to stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gz9zqs?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want  width: 208px; and  height: 250px; always even during the rotate, so I think I need also a zoom during the rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing code for manually rotating images, you can use Renderer2 which is an Angular feature.

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-undo btn-lg imagepreview" (click)="rotateImage('left')">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-undo btn-lg imagepreview" (click)="rotateImage('right')">
```

In TS file,

`import {Renderer2} from '@angular/core';`

In Constructor add this,

```
private renderer: Renderer2
```

Add this method

```
rotateImage(direction) {
    this.angle += direction == 'left' ? -90 : 90;
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.querySelector('.imagepreview'), 'transform', `rotate(${this.angle}deg)`);
  }
```